# multiple jquery functions not working

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I'm writing a html page where there are 1 different jquery operations done.

1. Selecting dates from jquery datepicker plugin.
2. Getting data from database for auto complete.

And below is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and
    JSON</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="autocompleter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and JSON</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="search-container">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
    </p>
    <div id="resultarea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**autocompleter.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "Controller",
                    type : "GET",
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    dataType : "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here, fetching the data for displaying name is working fine, but the datepicker is not working as expected. But when i use the below code. (Removing the datepicker from and pasting it in index.html header's script tag). The datepicker is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and
    JSON</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="autocompleter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Autocomplete in java web application using Jquery and JSON</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="search-container">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
    </p>
    <div id="resultarea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to know where am I going wrong. And why the second code works and why doesn't the first.

One of my teachers suggested that making HTML in plain and linking all the css and js would be a good design approach, So I wanted to separate the js file from HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Both functions can fit in just one `$(document).ready(...`

Comment: `autocompleter.js` has two `$(document).ready(function(){});` where only one should exist for the entire document. This function is the equivalent of saying *do this when the page loads*, but you have it twice, that is a conflict of interest, you should only need one and put all your code in there

Comment: To add to my previous comment, as a rule of thumb: all your javascript/jquery `<script>` tags should be written *after* your `<body>` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you wrapping this in *two* `document.ready` handlers?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
    });
});
```

Note the difference from the "working" version:

```
$(function() {
    $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
});
```

When you do this in jQuery:

```
$(function () { /.../ });
```

It attaches that function to the `document.ready` event.  Which means your **working** version says:

> On `document.ready`, initialize the date pickers.

And your **non-working** version says:

> On `document.ready`, attach another function to the `document.ready` handler which itself will initialize the date pickers.

Since `document.ready` only happens *once*, your second handler function will never execute.

You *already have* a "working" version, so use that:

```
$(function() {
    $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: for the sake of it, edit this good answer and add that they should always add their script tags after the `<body>`

Comment: @AGE: While that's often good advice, it's somewhat irrelevant to the question.  For the code presented it really wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Agreed, I just thought it would make a good addition to your answer

Comment: Thanks @AGE, this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Remove both of your upper level `$(function() {});` inside your `$(document).ready();` functions and it should work fine.

Both do the same "When doc is ready do this...", so its unnecessary to have them both and problematic to have them nested.

Your first piece of code isn't working because, **your script waits for the document to be ready to execute a function that waits for the document to be ready**, and that already happened.

The second one executes the code when the document is ready as usual.